# get machine time in air/as3

Tags: actionscript-3, time, air

Is there a way to get a reliable machine time that cannot be altered by changing the time/date on a mobile device or computer?

I'm looking to find a way to see time elapsed in an air app where you can...

- run the app
- change the system time (back an hour, or change the date forward by two weeks, etc.)
- run the app again with the correct time passed

any ideas how to implement this without relying on server connection?

Comment: What would be observably different between changing the date forward by two weeks, or just not running the application again for two weeks?

Comment: the actual time that has elapsed, in on case it's less than a minute, in another it's two weeks.

Comment: @Anon - I think you're actually just rephrasing OP's question - how can the app tell the difference between two weeks in 'real time' as opposed to two weeks in 'system time.'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel fairly confident saying it can't be done. Without a remote server to ping, all the app knows is what the OS tells it - and if the app isn't running, it can't be collecting its own data independently of the OS.

The closest you could get would be storing the system time at app shutdown, then comparing that to the system time on app startup to see if the OS' clock has been turned back - if the current time is *before* the previous time, you know something's up. Even then, the data about the last known system time has to be stored somewhere locally - which means the user is free to edit it if they want.

You could also mess with having the app running in the background constantly, or even as a service, though that moves out of the viability of using AIR - and even then, time would only pass while the system was on, and only if the user decides to let the background process continue running.

Comment: I figured as much, but while I do a lot of stuff with as3, I rarely work with air, so I thought I'd check. If someone can think of a way I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is measuring the elapsed time between two moments, [getTimer](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer%28%29) should do the job.

Comment: This only works if the app runs continually. The original question (seems to) asks about running it, shutting it down, and running it again. (though its not overly clear) Which to the best of my knowledge is not possible.

Comment: @Tyler Egeto. Thanks. You're right, it thought the question was about getting the time elapsed while the app was running.